# Can't binding ObservableCollection to ListView by MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

on Xamarin Form, has rows data but no content and only display one row and its empty.

In Model :

```
 public class Item
    {
        public string kind { get; set; }
        public string etag { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public Snippet snippet { get; set; }
        public ContentDetails contentDetails { get; set; }
        public Status status { get; set; }
        public Statistics statistics { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string kind { get; set; }
        public string etag { get; set; }
        public string nextPageToken { get; set; }
        public PageInfo pageInfo { get; set; }
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    }
```

In ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<TrendingModel.RootObject> _trendingRoots;
    private readonly ITrendingService _trendingService;


    public ObservableCollection<TrendingModel.RootObject> TrendingRoots
    {
        get { return _trendingRoots; }
        set
        {
            _trendingRoots = value;
            RaiseProtertyChanged(()=>TrendingRoots);
        }
    }
```

......

```
TrendingRoots = new ObservableCollection<TrendingModel.RootObject>(ridesResult);
```

The results is 'TredingRoots' -> TrendinRoot[0].items[i].snippet.....
On View, ListView :

```
 <ListView x:Name="lstHome" ItemsSource="{Binding TrendingRoots}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout
                           Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <Image 
                               Source="{Binding items.snippet.thumbnails.medium}"
                               Aspect="AspectFit"
                               WidthRequest="220"
                               HeightRequest="220"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <Label 
                               Text="{Binding items.snippet.title}"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="Center">

                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The final result is listview has 1 item and this item is empty, in while,

- The result must have 15 items.
- Display each item on listview item(currently it is empty, can't binding)

Comment: Please provide some additional information. It's not clear what you want to achiev.

Comment: Your ItemSource should be the items property of your RootObject, not a collection of RootObjects

Comment: updated. The data are 15 items but it can't binding to listview.

Comment: The problem is your binding in the ItemTemplate: `{Binding items.snippet.title}`. `items` is a list and it's not possible to bind list items to a single text element. If you want to show all items, you have to implement another ListView in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: @Jason so It did n't

Comment: @S.Spindler 'you have to implement another ListView in the ItemTemplate'. I don't understand why do I must implement another ListView in Item Template

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? do you want to show snippet.title for each item in RootObject in one label?

Comment: 15 items will display on listview with binding to property such as title, thumbnail.medium...

Comment: Because I guess you want to display your root objects with their items. So you would have a list of sub-items for each root object. As it is not clear what your goal is, I tried to guess what you want to do :]

Answer (score 1):

```
<ListView x:Name="lstHome" ItemsSource="{Binding TrendingRoots[0].items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout
                       Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Image 
                           Source="{Binding  snippet.thumbnails.medium}"
                           Aspect="AspectFit"
                           WidthRequest="220"
                           HeightRequest="220"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <Label 
                           Text="{Binding snippet.title}"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center">

                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```